# Is there an <experimental/filesystem> move operation I am missing?

Tags: c++, move

Is there a move() function I am missing? Best I have come up with is a hardlinked copy followed by delete original, but it doesn't fill me with confidence having to manually manage the two operations, nor does it work across filesystems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not called move but rename.

[std::filesystem::rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename)

> Moves or renames the filesystem object identified by old_p to new_p as if by the POSIX rename

```
 void rename(const std::filesystem::path& old_p,
             const std::filesystem::path& new_p);

 void rename(const std::filesystem::path& old_p,  // (since C++17)
             const std::filesystem::path& new_p,
             std::error_code& ec) noexcept;
```